# how to give an aliasname to like operator in mysql

Tags: mysql, sql, column-alias

I want to select the name like 'Bo%' or name like 'Ni%' from a table and I want to give a specific name to all that name like Bo and a specific name to all that name like Ni.
But if I give an alias name as this it not works.

name like 'Bo%' as Male or name like'Ni%' as female.
So how can I do this?

Answer (score 1):

SQL allows you to alias columns, or tables.  You can't alternate a column name on a per value basis -- the name needs to be consistent so you can reference it for later operations.

You need to dedicate a column to each option you want to see:

```
SELECT CASE WHEN t.col LIKE 'Bo%' THEN t.col ELSE NULL END AS male,
       CASE WHEN t.col LIKE 'Ni%' THEN t.col ELSE NULL END AS female
  FROM YOUR_TABLE t
```

...but that means the male or female column could be null -- both will be if neither `LIKE` matches:

```
name    male  female
-------------------
Bob     Bob   NULL
Nirmal  NULL  Nirmal
Xander  NULL  NULL
```